# Bad math environment delimiter. \end{align}

Tags: equations, compilation-error

I'd need help regarding this small piece of code. During the compilation the error message 'Bad math environment delimiter. \end{align}' appears, and the pdf looks like the image below:

```
\begin{align}
%
S(f;r) = \mathfrak{F}\{ \mathbf{s}(t - \tau)exp^{- jk_{0}R}  \} \\
 = \(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf{s}(t-\tau)exp^{-jk_{0}R}exp^{-2\pi jft} \,dt\) 
%
\end{align}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `\(... \) `? Jyst use `() `

Comment: And the code you provide will not compile. Never ignore compilation errors just because you actually get a pdf file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

- The immediate cause of the error message is that the second row contains `\(` and `\)`, which are directives to start and end *inline math* mode. But since the formula is already in math mode -- *display math* mode, to be exact -- the directives `\(` and `\)` are not legal, and TeX is telling you about this infraction. (I agree that the error message is a tad terse and could be a bit more descriptive.)
- My best guess -- which may well be wrong! -- is that `\(` and `\)` appear in the second row because you copied and pasted the integral expression from an inline math setting into the display math setting. The upshot? Do *not* use `\(` and `\)` while in display math.
- A separate comment: You use an `align` environment, but you provide no `&` alignment points. I think the two-row expression would look a lot better if you aligned the rows on their `=` symbols.

[image]

*Additional observation*, prompted by a comment by @egreg: Observe that the `align` environment produces a separate equation number for each row by default. (This default may be overridden via suitably placed `\notag` or `\nonumber` directives.) If it's your intention that the entire two-line expression should have a single equation number, it would be better to cater to this fact by replacing the `align` environment with either a nested `equation`/`split` or a nested `equation`/`aligned` pair of environments. Using a `split` environment will place the lone equation number vertically centered across rows, while an `aligned` environment lets you provide an option to inform LaTeX that the equation number should be placed on the top or bottom row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
%
S(f;r) &= \mathfrak{F}\bigl\{ \mathbf{s}(t - \tau)\exp^{- jk_{0}R}  \bigr\} \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf{s}(t-\tau)\exp^{-jk_{0}R}\exp^{-2\pi jft} \,dt
%
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, although split seems better here

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I did think about switching to a `split` or `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment, but in the end I decided it against it, in case the OP has a reason for generating two separate equation numbers. I'll post an addendum to point this out more explicitly.